# How Can I make Image Field in Django ModelForm Required

Tags: python, django

I have a Django ModelForm with an image field and I want to add validation on empty image form field. That is, I want system validation message display when user did not select an image.

I have tried but it is not working as I expected because my Validation Error Message displays only when the user selection is not an image but processes the form on none selection. In short I want to add a required attribute to the image field thereby compelling the user to select a valid image before proceeding. Remember that there is an avatar.jpg default in the database but upon user profile I want him or her to change it before proceeding.
Here is my Model code:

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [ 'image']

    def clean_image(self):
       image = self.cleaned_data.get('image')
       if not image or image == "":
           raise forms.ValidationError(('Invalid value'), code='invalid') 
       return image
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the field required using the `__init__()` method:

```py
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [ 'image']

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['image'].required = True
```

You could also change the Profile model by making sure the image cannot be null/blank. This could be done with `models.ImageField([..], blank=False, null=False)`

Comment: I have added blank=False, null=False and applied the solution you provided but nothing is working

Comment: @apollos **blank=False** and **null=False** works when you don't run **migration**  for the first time. After you run your migrations without **blank=False** and **null=False** the field must **blank=True** and **null=True**. How did you solve this problem with **blank=False** and **null=False**  while running migration without them for the first time.